# Unable to update Xcode (item temporarily unavailable)?

Tags: xcode, macos, updates

I tried completely uninstalling Xcode but it still says "update" in the App Store. When i try to update it, it just says that the item is temporarily unavailable, asking me to try again later. I am currently using OSX Yosemite 10.10.1 to update it to Version 6.1.1. How can i solve this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Trouble downloading XCode 6.1 on Mac OS X Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27073615/608639) on Stack Overflow and [Xcode 6.1 unavaliable](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6622317) on Apple Support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> to update it to Version 6.1.1

In your Web browser, sign into the [Apple developr site](http://developer.apple.com) and then click this link:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

Xcode 6.1.1 is the first link, at the top of that page. Click it!

Comment: I had the same problem trying to get the Xcode 6.3.1 update to work.  This answer also solved my issues.

Comment: This answer is a workaround to download the latest version, but if you want to get Xcode installs working again via the Mac App Store (which seems desirable given the original question, plus it will prompt you to update or auto-update in the future), try TMin's answer.

Answer (score 41):

Try going to the "App Store" > "Store" > "Check for Unfinished Downloads ..."

This fixed the bug for me, but I'm still running Mavericks.

Comment: I cant believe this fixed the issue :S.. several months later, I finally can install again... and it was sooo simple :S

Comment: Helps with newer versions of XCode too (6.3.1 in my case), thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on Yosemite too. I believe this should be the accepted answer, as it resolves the original problem rather than offering a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I had the same problem recently.

It turns out I was using the Canadian app store, but my Apple ID is for the UK store. The app store didn't tell me that this was the case until I followed Tmin's advice:

> Try going to the "App Store" > "Store" > "Check for Unfinished Downloads ..."

Doing that prompted me to switch to the UK app store. I was then able to update all my apps.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the Cache Problem. It occurs a lot in Yosemite :(
Download [Yosemite Cache Cleaner](http://www.northernsoftworks.com/yosemitecachecleaner.html) software.
Its a trail version, but you can delete it after you clean your cache.
Then rebooting mac should resolve the problem.