# Trouble downloading XCode 6.2 on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.5.) and Yosemite (10.10.2)

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite, xcode-6.2

I can not download Xcode 6.2. I tried upgrading it and it doesn't work. I have successfully downloaded 6.2. beta 5 but can't download the full version.

I am using Chrome and safari. I had multiple network errors , connection breaks and it this isn't my problem. The problem is that the download comes to 2.6/2.6 and does not finalize it. The file is still named "Xcode_6.2.dmg.crdownload". I tried:

- renaming the file To Xcode.6.2.dmg
- to Xcode6.dmg (with one dot)
- open package content and run XCode6.2.dmg

and I alsways get the following error: 
"The following disk images couldn't be opened"
"Xcode6.dmg"  Reason = image not recognized.

Some times the downloaded file which said to be finished had only 726 MB disk size, even the browser AND Finder said it had 2.6/2.6Gb (I found this out by "Get Info" for the download file).

I also followed this so : 
[How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-and-get-the-dmg-file)

and this:

[Trouble downloading XCode 6.1 on Mac OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073615/trouble-downloading-xcode-6-1-on-mac-os-x-yosemite)

None helped. I also tried:

- downloading via wget
- resuming via wget
- download from a different internet connection/IP
- from different machines: Mac mini 2009, 2013, Mac Pro 2012
- from different OS versions Mac Mavericks and Yosemite
- from different accounts: iOS Developer and iOS Enterprise Developer
- from different download links
- from different browsers: Safari, Chrome
- updating Xcode 6.1.1 to Xcode 6.2.
- few more so answers which I don't have here

Here is my terminal output:

```
Mac-mini:~ W_MB$ sudo find / -name *XCode*
/Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/PlugIns/Compressor/CompressorKit.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/ProMediaIO/Components/IMXCodec.component
/Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/PlugIns/Compressor/CompressorKit.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/ProMediaIO/Components/IMXCodec.component/Contents/MacOS/IMXCodec
/Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/PlugIns/Compressor/CompressorKit.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/ProMediaIO/Components/IMXCodec.component/Contents/Resources/IMXCodec.rsrc
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsInterface.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/PBXCodeAssistant.nib
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

I am beggining to run out of ideas what to try next and how to solve the problem. I also wonder if it is a problem on the apple-server-side.
I need to finish my project in 2-3 weeks and I am having real problems with this XCode update. Any ideas or solutions are welcome, I will try them.

UPDATE (17.04.2015.):

I have successfully downloaded Xcode 6.3 but only after several downloads. I had once the same error like before. The download did go to 100/100% but didn't finish and I had once a "package corrupt" error. I also downloaded Xcode 6.3 onto my late 2009 mac mini (Mavericks) and had the corrupt package error while on my mac mini 2012 (Yosemite) the same .dmg file worked...

Comment: Why don't you just get it via the AppStore.

Comment: Tried the App Store?

Comment: Yes i tried via appstore. Clicked the get -- Install and it failed twice. Beside that it didn't work I was unable to work in Xcode while the download/update was in progress. However, I didn't try it on the Mavericks Machine. I also tried to restore app store downloads which didn't work for : Xcode, iMovie and similar apps... After I my download "finishes" for the 8th time I will try it on my Mavericks machine, maybe it works. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Tried the app store. Download failed at 2.58 of 2.58Gb on Mavericks 10.9.5. aswell. Another download on another link also failed. I really have no clue why, runned out of ideas aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your network errors: I think if multiple machines have the same problem then you should go somewhere else, like to libraries with free wifi to see if it works  there.

I recommend to deinstall Xcode 6.2beta and any other Xcode copies you have. (maybe save them to an external hard drive so you have a backup) You can do this using CleanMyMac (not sure if deinstall is included in a trial version).

After deinstalling I would try to download it from the AppStore since that will give you the most stable internet connection.

If that still does not work, try again downloading Xcode from Apple's Member Center.

No progress? Then use the beta to finish your project and send a support request to Apple (they offer phone support now which is quite a lot faster)

Good luck and hope it helps :)

Comment: Deinstallation, great idea. Gonna do it right away on my mavericks machine. By tommorrow I will now if it worked. And fresh install can be copied or redone on my other machines =). Gonna try :)

Comment: Ok, the uninstall and redownload from appstore also failed with a AppStore error Xcode failed to download and try again. I can start the "Install" process again. Tried it on Mavericks mac mini late 2009. My friend says he downloaded the .dmg file onto a win7 laptop from a 100 MB library network. I will check the file. I will also install the Xcode 6.2 beta 5. I will send a support request if the .dmg file doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, on which OS X are you currently?

Comment: Hm thought that might change something. Did you go to some other place to download the .dmg? You might possibly try to download an older version of Xcode (from the member center) to see wether it is about some incompatibility or so...(don't think so but, give it a shot ;) )

Comment: I started downloads from many different location cycling from DEV center to others (and appstore too). I will try to dl a older version. That way I will know if it is maybe accout based, if such a thing can happen. It might be due the face that I transfered the same developer account from one machine to another via XCode eksport developer profile. I am gonna check this out too.

Answer (score 1):

I  the had the same problem yesterday.
Here is what i did to solve it.

1. Quit the app store.
2. Open temo directory. (in terminal type : open $TMPDIR)
3. Delete all the files in tempdir.
4. Then restart the macbook (Don't know does it count or not but i just did it).
5. Start the update process in app store again.

it worked for me.u can try it.
Good luck!

Cheers,

Harshal

Comment: I got an AppStore error message saying :"Xcode failed to download"."Use the Purchase page to try again.". The download bar is 80% full with 2.58 Gb of 2.58 Gb and yet it didn't install or finish the download. I will try again with another AppStore account. Might get lucky or something. Later I will try the XCode 6.2. beta 5 download

Comment: I changed my apple appstore account while the 2.58 Gb of 2.58 Gb message was shown and started the install process and it got stuck in "waiting for install...". I then cleared the cache, deleted the download with holding the option key and now XCode is being downloaded again however the download Icon is "pulsing" (it is hidden, and is being shown when a download tick occurs - every 1 Mb). Somehow this doesn't supprise me... :-S

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think this is because you downloaded your current version of Xcode from online. Now that you try to update it as an app, it runs into some kind of problem. I have the exact same problem, and I fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode from the app store. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved itself somehow...
Here is what I did. First I unistalled the old version of Xcode. Then I downloaded it from the appStore. Then the download got stuck at 2.58 of 2.58 Gb. Then I quit the app store and relaunched it. This time I signed in with a different account. Suddenly the app went to "Installing" state a stuck there. Then I restarted the mac and when I reopened "Launchpa" There was a new Icon of Xcode and it works. I did this on my Mac mini with Mavericks. I copied the whole app folder onto my mac pro and it works with some minor errors. But I got Xcode/simulator up and running in the end. This is not a REAL solution, and I haven't found out why it worked. I just posted the solution because it maybe help someone, somehow...
Thank you guys for your help. I combined all your solutions and in the end it worked a bit diffrently :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem befoure. Here is what i did to solve it.

here are two way to download Xcode 6,Upgrade OSX....etc,i have download successfully

1 Download The Xcode from a different internet connection/IP (i will suggest, you should use dongle instead of WIFI)

or

2:trying to download US Network throw the VPN

Thanks
Sushil